# Oracle form builder linux

Tags: linux, oracle, oracleforms, formbuilder

I download oracle form builder for linux , but the following error occurred , when I try 
To run in :

```
~/OraHome_1/bin$ ./frmbld

There was an error trying to initialize the HPI library.
Please check your installation, HotSpot does not work correctly
when installed in the JDK 1.2 Linux Production Release, or
with any JDK 1.1.x release.
There was an error trying to initialize the HPI library.
Please check your installation, HotSpot does not work correctly
when installed in the JDK 1.2 Linux Production Release, or
with any JDK 1.1.x release.
FRM-10039: Unable to start up the Form Builder.
```

OS : Ubuntu 10.10

**Java info :**

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: So, which version of the JDK have you got on your box?

Comment: i update the post , but i think there is jdk inside /home/user1/OraHome_1

Comment: @shox, that doesn't mean the system is using it. Try to install Oracle's Java instead and point your environment to it. (I've had problems in the past where Oracle did funny things when pointing at non-Oracle -- then Sun -- Java.)

Comment: may I ask which version of Oracle form builder did you download and install?

Answer (score 2):

It can be resolved by installing below lib:

```
sudo dnf install libnsl
```

This solution worked for me.

Comment: Awesome!
Same issue here when trying to install an old Oracle JDK5u81 on OL8. 
Your solution worked for me as well.